# RVEST for Dates in HTML files

Tags: html, r, date, web-scraping, rvest

I'm attempting to scrape the date out of saved HTML files. Either, the last-modified date, or the published date, whichever the file has.  What I have is not working and I think it's because it's not reading the script from the HTML file, but rather looking just at the directory where the files are stored.

I have a directory with several hundred saved HTML files that need to be processed for:
HTML Name
Date
Date Saved to Directory (this is less important as I have the original scraping date)

The code I have so far:

```
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

setwd("D:/URLtoDateTest")

file_list <- list.files(path = 'D:/URLtoDateTest')
html_data <- data.frame(file_list)

for (i in 1:length(html_names)){
  rawHTML <- lapply(html_data, function(html){
    read_html(html)
}

html_data$date <- read_html(file_list) %>%
  html_nodes("div.review-content-header__dates") %>%
  html_attr("datetime")
```

Any suggestions?

I've updated the code to the following:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

setwd("D:/URLtoDateTest")

#get list of html files
htmlfiles <- list.files(pattern= "html$")

#loop through the list of files
returneddates <- sapply(htmlfiles, function(file){
  #read file and retrieve the date time
  datetime <-read_html(file) %>%
    html_nodes("div.review-content-header__dates") %>%
    html_attr("datetime")
  datetime
})

#conbine into a dataframe
answer <- data.frame(htmlfiles, returneddates)
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
> answer <- data.frame(htmlfiles, returneddates)
Error in data.frame(htmlfiles, returneddates) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 40, 0
```

and finally for the datetime:

```
character(0)
```

Example of page to be scraped (modified to remove all references to actual page/organization this belongs to).

```
</script>
    <title>Web Site Disclaimers | Other | ORG</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Page Title Example"/>     <meta name="keywords" content="ORG,  Full Organization Name,  other,  about,  about ORG.gov,  web site disclaimers,  flash disclaimers,  policies and regulations,  image reuse terms and conditions,  key matches,  linking,  linking to ORG.gov,  why link to ORG.gov,  how to link to ORG.gov,  graphic link to ORG.gov,  text link to describe ORG.gov,  questions or comments,  search tips,  site map,  web page badges and buttons,  other languages,  most spoken languages, Policies &amp; Guidelines"/>                       <meta name="robots" content="index, archive" />         <meta property="ORG:template_version" content="4.0"/>
    <meta property="ORG:last_updated" content="December 12, 2019"/>
    <meta property="ORG:last_reviewed" content="December 12, 2019"/>
    <meta property="ORG:content_source" content="Full Organizatio Name"/>
    <meta property="ORG:maintained_by" content="OFFICE OF COMMUNICATION; DIGITAL MEDIA BRANCH"/>
    <meta property="ORG:content_id" content="6318" />
            <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.ORG.gov/other/disclaimer.html"/>    <meta property="ORG:wcms_build" content="4.8.11 - b.2268" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/other/wcms-inc/localrd.css"/>     <style>
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {height: 100%; max-height: 100%;} 
</style>        <!-- CSS Added Dynamically Here -->     <meta name="DC.date" content="2019-12-13T01:52:39Z" />
                <meta name="ORG:last_published" content="2019-12-13T15:31:13Z" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `read_html()` can only take a single value to read.  In your attempts above you are trying to pass either a data frame or an entire list.

Your script should look something like:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

#get list of html files
htmlfiles <- list.files(pattern= "html$")

#loop through the list of files
returneddates <- sapply(htmlfiles, function(file){
   #read file and retrieve the date time
   datetime <-read_html(file) %>%
             html_node(xpath = ".//meta[@property = 'ORG:last_updated']") %>% 
             html_attr("content")
   datetime
})

#combine into a dataframe
answer <- data.frame(htmlfiles, returneddates)
```

**Debugging help**

```
   htmlfiles <- htmlfiles[1:2] #reduce the file list down for debugging
    
    returneddates <- sapply(htmlfiles, function(file){
       print(file)  #are you opening the correct file?
       #read file and retrieve the date time
       page <-read_html(file) 
       divReview <- page %>% html_nodes("div.review-content-header__dates") 
       print(divReview) #is a single node found?
       datetime <- divReview%>% html_attr("datetime")
       print(datetime)   #are you extracting the correct attribute?
       datetime
    })
```

** Update 2 - Based in html snippet**

The last modified date is stored in the content attribute of a meta tag.  Based on the html snippet to retrieve that information this should work

```
page<-read_html('   <title>Web Site Disclaimers | Other | ORG</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Page Title Example"/>     <meta name="keywords" content="ORG,  Full Organization Name,  other,  about,  about ORG.gov,  web site disclaimers,  flash disclaimers,  policies and regulations,  image reuse terms and conditions,  key matches,  linking,  linking to ORG.gov,  why link to ORG.gov,  how to link to ORG.gov,  graphic link to ORG.gov,  text link to describe ORG.gov,  questions or comments,  search tips,  site map,  web page badges and buttons,  other languages,  most spoken languages, Policies &amp; Guidelines"/>                       <meta name="robots" content="index, archive" />         <meta property="ORG:template_version" content="4.0"/>
    <meta property="ORG:last_updated" content="December 12, 2019"/>
    <meta property="ORG:last_reviewed" content="December 12, 2019"/>
    <meta property="ORG:content_source" content="Full Organizatio Name"/>
    <meta property="ORG:maintained_by" content="OFFICE OF COMMUNICATION; DIGITAL MEDIA BRANCH"/>
    <meta property="ORG:content_id" content="6318" />
            <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.ORG.gov/other/disclaimer.html"/>    <meta property="ORG:wcms_build" content="4.8.11 - b.2268" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/other/wcms-inc/localrd.css"/>     <style>
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {height: 100%; max-height: 100%;} 
</style>        <!-- CSS Added Dynamically Here -->     <meta name="DC.date" content="2019-12-13T01:52:39Z" />
                <meta name="ORG:last_published" content="2019-12-13T15:31:13Z" />')

#get the meta node where the property attribute = ORG:last_updated,
# then retrieve the data stored in the content attribute.
lastupdate <- page %>% html_node(xpath = ".//meta[@property = 'ORG:last_updated']") %>% html_attr("content")
lastreview <- page %>% html_node(xpath = ".//meta[@property = 'ORG:last_reviewed']") %>% html_attr("content")
```

Comment: thank you! I feel like I'm so close, but this code is now returning this error: 
> answer <- data.frame(htmlfiles, returneddates)
Error in data.frame(htmlfiles, returneddates) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 40, 0
Any thoughts why?

Comment: From the error message, it looks like you have 40 html files, but for some reason the sapply seems to be returning a zero length vector.  Thus I am guessing there is a mistake with html_nodes or html_attr function calls.  May need to add a print statement or two to ensure you are getting the expected response back.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I added the print statements above - I'm not very familiar with html/Rvest in this manner, so I truly appreciate your help. It almost seems like it's hitting the snag at the datetime segment.

Comment: Thanks again, I appreciate your assistance with this. I ran the debugging section and this is what it returned: 
[1] "background.html"
{xml_nodeset (0)}
character(0)
[1] "disclaimer.html"
{xml_nodeset (0)}
character(0)
Some of these files may not contain a date and that's fine - but the disclaimer.html file has dates in the header under the script tag in <meta property>.

Comment: It looks like html_nodes is incorrect and not finding the correct tag.  Also, if some files doesn’t contain the date, use html_node without the s, this will always return a value, even if it is NA.  Sorry without a sample can’t help with finding the correct tag.

Comment: I added an example of the header of one of the pages in my list (removed references to actual page as it is not my personal content).

Comment: See the latest update and revised code script.

Comment: You are amazing, thank you!! This works beautifully!! The only other question I have and truly thank you for your time, is, assuming I have different organizations, is it possible to only match the "last_updated" piece of that string?

Comment: Something like: `html_node(xpath = ".//meta[contains(@property, 'last_reviewed')]")`

Comment: This version doesn't return anything for the initial ORG or the other ones I have.

Comment: Nevermind - I uninstalled/reinstalled the rvest package and now it works perfectly

Comment: I tried the code on a larger dataset, and it returned this error: "Error in UseMethod("xml_find_first") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_first' applied to an object of class "xml_document"
Called from: xml2::xml_find_first(x, make_selector(css, xpath))"

Comment: Be sure both the rvest and xml2 packages are loaded.  I’m not sure what else could be the problem