# Generalizing Meta[@property=...] to include all tags that contain a phrase

Tags: html, r, tags, rvest

I have a bit of code in R using RVEST that is intended to identify the "last-updated" date given by an organization for their URL. The code parses the .html files and returns the "last_update" piece but I need to generalize it so that it is not organization specific.

I'm using the word "ORG" as a placeholder for the example organization. What I have right now is:

```
dates <- sapply(htmlfiles, function(file){
  #read file and retrieve the date time
  datetime <-read_html(file) %>%
    html_node(xpath = ".//meta[@property = 'ORG:last_updated']") %>% 
    html_attr("content")
  datetime
})
```

and what I need it to be is something similar to:

```
html_node(xpath = ".//meta[contains(@property, 'last_reviewed')]")
```

The HTML code looks something like this:

```
page<-read_html('   <title>Web Site Disclaimers | Other | ORG</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Page Title Example"/>     <meta name="keywords" content="ORG,  Full Organization Name,  other,  about,  about ORG.gov,  web site disclaimers,  flash disclaimers,  policies and regulations,  image reuse terms and conditions,  key matches,  linking,  linking to ORG.gov,  why link to ORG.gov,  how to link to ORG.gov,  graphic link to ORG.gov,  text link to describe ORG.gov,  questions or comments,  search tips,  site map,  web page badges and buttons,  other languages,  most spoken languages, Policies &amp; Guidelines"/>                       <meta name="robots" content="index, archive" />         <meta property="ORG:template_version" content="4.0"/>
    <meta property="ORG:last_updated" content="December 12, 2019"/>
    <meta property="ORG:last_reviewed" content="December 12, 2019"/>
    <meta property="ORG:content_source" content="Full Organizatio Name"/>
    <meta property="ORG:maintained_by" content="OFFICE OF COMMUNICATION; DIGITAL MEDIA BRANCH"/>
    <meta property="ORG:content_id" content="6318" />
            <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.ORG.gov/other/disclaimer.html"/>    <meta property="ORG:wcms_build" content="4.8.11 - b.2268" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/other/wcms-inc/localrd.css"/>     <style>
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {height: 100%; max-height: 100%;} 
</style>        <!-- CSS Added Dynamically Here -->     <meta name="DC.date" content="2019-12-13T01:52:39Z" />
                <meta name="ORG:last_published" content="2019-12-13T15:31:13Z" />')

#get the meta node where the property attribute = ORG:last_updated,
# then retrieve the data stored in the content attribute.
lastupdate <- page %>% html_node(xpath = ".//meta[@property = 'ORG:last_updated']") %>% html_attr("content")
lastreview <- page %>% html_node(xpath = ".//meta[@property = 'ORG:last_reviewed']") %>% html_attr("content")
```

But this does not work, and retrieves null values for all HTMLs.  When I used the original code, I did retrieve dates, so I know they exist. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Updated to include the loop that is pulling the dates and a sample of the HTML code that I need to parse. The ORG can vary and that's where I'm having the issue.

Comment: If I run the code in your example, I get the correct values returned. I don't get NULL. Tested with `rvest_0.3.5`

Comment: With this piece: html_node(xpath = ".//meta[contains(@property, 'last_reviewed')]") 
Or what's in the original code? The original code works great for ORG1, but there are other organizations that have different names before the ":last_updated"

Comment: This returns a date: `page %>% html_node(xpath = ".//meta[contains(@property, 'last_updated')]") %>% html_attr("content")`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: It is, but for me it doesn't return a date, I am using rvest v 1.0.0 though, so I wonder if that's the issue

Comment: I just updated to `rvest_1.0.0` and it still works just fine on the example you provided. Have you also tried running this in a fresh R session?

Comment: I did, but I just uninstalled and reinstalled rvest and now it's working?? Oy, thank you for your help!

Comment: Original question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66924899/rvest-for-dates-in-html-files/66926645?noredirect=1#comment118427129_66926645